# Using a subquery in a LIKE statement

Tags: mysql, subquery, like

I need to write a subquery inside a LIKE statement. This subquery would return me a word that I need to find in the middle of a sentence (that belongs to another field). Is it possible? This is how I'm trying (and failing):

```
select nm_linha from linhas where cidades_origem like '%SUBQUERY HERE WOULD GO HERE%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work :

```
select nm_linha from linhas where cidades_origem like CONCAT('%', (subquery_goes_here) ,'%')
```

For example :

```
SELECT * 
FROM films
WHERE titre LIKE CONCAT('%', (SELECT  'fella'),  '%')

+---------+------------+
| id      | titre      |
+---------+------------+
|       1 | Goodfellas |
+---------+------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```